# Trying to rebuild Python embedded C++ DLL and getting "LNK2001: ... Py_Intitialize" and similiar errors?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to rebuild a C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2013 used to embed a Python module after making a subtle change and I am running into a number of

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Intitialize
```

and similar errors.

The pretty much the only difference between the machine that was able to build the DLL originally is it had Python installed natively whereas this machine has it installed through Anaconda.

In configurations properties I changed the following to

- C\C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories ->
  C:\Users\ **name**\Anaconda3\include
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories ->
  C:\Users\ **name**\Anaconda3\libs

[image]

But for some reason I am still generating these areas ... any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Can you show a couple more lines of the linking error? Also include the `link.exe` command used to perform the linking.

Comment: Does it start with `__simp__` or `__imp__ `?

Comment: Added a screenshot to original post. greatwolf - I am not sure how to include the link.exe command

Comment: Those are python functions from the C API. If it's not resolving it probably means you're not including the python import library. You'll have to check how the `link.exe` is being called what exactly is being passed in. You should find this info under the compile log section or the generated html log file.